# Is it possible to get informations about devices in the HDCP chain?

Tags: windows, winapi, drm, hdcp

I would like to protect my windows software from unwanted devices (splitters, capture/grabbers devices) in HDCP chain, allowing only whitelisted devices. Is it possible?

I couldn't find anything in the windows api documentation.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use Output Protection Manager (OPM) to protect video content as it travels over a physical connector to a display device. And you could start from the Doc:[Using Output Protection Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/using-output-protection-manager)

Comment: SetWindowDisplayAffinity with WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE should be an easy start https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity or use WinRT's `Windows.Media.Protection` namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.protection for ex: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.protection.hdcpsession